# Paragraphs in \thanks

Tags: footnotes, paragraphs

Paragraphs don't seem to work in a `\thanks` footnote, which surprised me. Why is that so, and what would be the best workaround?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\title{Some Title}
\author{My Name%
\thanks{%
  Thanks footnote, first paragraph.

  Thanks footnote, second paragraph.
}}
\maketitle

Some text.%
\footnote{
Footnote 1, first paragraph.

Footnote 2, second paragraph.
} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: use `\endgraf` instead of the empty line.

Answer (score 6):

The `\author` macro is defined short, so its argument can't contain the token `\par` (which is what TeX sees for two consecutive newlines). As a workaround you can use `\endgraf` instead, which is the same but doesn't trigger that error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\title{Some Title}
\author{My Name%
\thanks{%
  Thanks footnote, first paragraph.\endgraf
  Thanks footnote, second paragraph.
}}
\maketitle

Some text.%
\footnote{
Footnote 1, first paragraph.

Footnote 2, second paragraph.
} 
\end{document}
```